# How to find similarity score of two word phrases with word2vec?

Tags: text-mining, gensim, word2vec

With word2vec, to find similarity score/most similar words of a single word can be done by

```
model.most_similar('man')
model.similarity('man', 'woman')
```

However, now i want to find similarity score of a word phrase, such as,

```
model.most_similar('battery life')
model.similarity('battery life', 'battery')
model.similarity('battery life', 'sound quality')
```

which i get the KeyError: "word 'battery life' not in vocabulary",
so is it possible to do it with word2vec?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what words are in the current word2vec model. If it is there you can access it by using `model.most_similar("battery_life")` since the library uses underscores to separate words in n-grams.

Comment: battery life is already in my training corpus, using model.most_similar("battery_life") still gives me the KeyError :( thx for your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that `word2vec` gives you embedding for words, not for phrases. There are several approaches in state-of-art to produce phrase embeddings. Some of them are:

- [Distributed Representations of Words and Phrases and their Compositionality](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5021-distributed-representations-of-words-and-phrases-and-their-compositionality.pdf)
- [Learning Composition Models for Phrase Embeddings](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/Q/Q15/Q15-1017.pdf)
- [Learning Continuous Phrase Representations and Syntactic Parsing with Recursive Neural Networks](http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/2010SocherManningNg.pdf)

These are good approaches to generate phrase embeddings.

But, if you simple want to get a phrase embedding from word embedding, then probably you can `concatenate/add/average` word embeddings of the words in a phrase.

For example:

```
phrase_embedding['battery life'] = word_embedding['battery'] + word_embedding['life']
```

Here, `'+'` represents concatenation of two word vectors.